# Getting source not available about reaching the end of the PROC

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to call a function that will output a string determining how "fast" you are going in your car using integers. The problem is that no matter what is in the eax register, it does not properly execute the ELSE IF loop and end the PROC.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc            ;Use Irvine32 library.

.data
    ;Declare variables here.

    speed BYTE ?, 0
    wTooFast BYTE "Woah! You are going way too fast! Slow down!", 0                     
    tooFast BYTE "You are going faster than the speed limit. Slow down.", 0                     
    speedLimit BYTE "You are maintaining an appopriate speed limit. Keep up being a safe driver!", 0                        
    tooSlow BYTE "You are going slower than the flow of traffic. Speed up.", 0                      
    wTooSlow BYTE "Is the engine even on? Speed up!", 0                     



.code
main PROC
    ;Write your code here.  

    target:
        call Randomize
        mov eax, 101
        call RandomRange
        .IF (eax <= 40)
        jmp target
        .ENDIF
    call WriteInt

    call SpeedVal
    mov edx, 0
    mov speed, al
    mov edx, OFFSET speed
    call WriteString
    call Crlf





    exit                        ;Exit program.
main ENDP

    SpeedVal PROC

        .IF (eax >= 85)
        mov al, wTooFast
        .ELSEIF (eax > 75) && (eax < 85)
        mov al, tooFast
        .ELSEIF (eax > 64) && (eax < 76)
        mov al, speedLimit
        .ELSEIF (eax > 54) && (eax < 65)
        mov al, tooSlow
        .ELSE
        mov al, wTooSlow
        .ENDIF


    SpeedVal ENDP



END main
```

it should output depending on what the random variable is one of the strings declared in the .data section.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot a `ret` so execution falls off the bottom of your `PROC`.  And the debugger just shows you "source not available" because I guess you're using a source view instead of disassembly view.

`PROC` / `ENDP` doesn't insert a `ret` instruction for you.